# I need to remove <p> tag to a field that only contains an URL

Tags: php, mysql, database

By mistake, I changed input by textareas, and wyswyg updated all the values like

```
`http://google.com/?search=...` (url)     to `<p>http://google.com/?search=...</p>`
```

What correct mysql sentence can i use to fix this? PHP `strip_tags()` won't work :(

Comment: `strip_tags` should do it. Why does it not work? What happens?

Comment: Did you replace the original data with the string "<p>url</p>" exactly as is? Because if you did, there's no way to get it back without restoring from backup. Sorry.

Comment: two examples (how does it look like and what do you expect) would be helpful as I am not sure what is exactly wrong.

Comment: OK, got so nervious that didn't even upload the proper file... strip_tags works, i'll fix it like this (query+PHP+query) I think unless you see a mysql query that can help

Answer (score 3):

Maybe something like this:

```
UPDATE table SET column = REPLACE(column, "<p>", "");
UPDATE table SET column = REPLACE(column, "</p>", "");
```

Untested and possibly harmful !

Here's the reference:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace

Comment: i could create a temporary field for so!

Answer (score 1):

Something along these lines perhaps:

```
UPDATE tablename SET columnname = TRIM(LEADING '<p>' FROM TRIM(TRAILING '</p>' FROM columnname));
```

This might be faster:

```
UPDATE tablename SET columnname = TRIM(LEADING '<p>' FROM TRIM(TRAILING '</p>' FROM columnname)) WHERE columnname LIKE '<p>%</p>';
```

References:

[TRIM (and other string functions)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim)

[LIKE (and other string comparison operators)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html)

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1      :(

Comment: Sorry, I missed a bracket there. Fixed!

Comment: I'm British, we call () brackets!